# Test the recurring payment failure in sandbox environment

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I have implemented the recurring payment for my MVC application in sandbox environment.
How do I test “recurring payment failure”?  I had written the code to cancel the “recurring profile”, when the third payment attempt fails. How do I test it?

Any help would be appreciable.

Thanks

Ranish

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17212090/testing-recurring-payments-in-the-paypal-sandbox